# delete/cut everything between 2 patterns (load to register) vim

Tags: vim

I need to delete everything between 2 patterns or   or rather cut that and put that ot register for latter use ( put it to different file)

```
%s/\V<se.\{-}<\/sel//gc
```

but this is only deletion (and it did not work and I want rather cut it and put it to register ( maybe I need some script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the global command would work.

```
let @a=''|g/startpattern/.+1,/stoppattern/-1 delete A
```

where

```
let @a=''                    - Clear the a register
g/startpattern/              - search for the start of the pattern
.+1,/stoppattern/-1 delete A - delete everything between start and stop and 
                               append it to register a
```

works for

```
startpattern
this goes to register A
so does this
stoppattern
```

but not for

```
startpattern this should go to register A stoppattern.
```

Comment: those `+1 -1` offset is line based isn't it? so you assume those patterns are whole line pattern.

Comment: @Kent - yes, I assumed the patterns would be on their own line. If they are indeed on the same line as what needs to be cut, this wont work.

Answer (score 2):

don't know exactly what the two patterns you want, but give this line a try:

```
s/pattern1\zs\_.\{-}\zepattern2/\=setreg('x',submatch(0))>-1:'':''/
```

- the two patterns here are `pattern1` and `pattern2`
- text (could be multiple lines) between the two patterns would be replaced by empty string, the two patterns them self will not be replaced.
- the "deleted" text will be saved in register `x`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pattern that matches exactly what you want to "cut", simply search for that pattern with a normal <kbd>/</kbd> search. Then you can use the `gn` object to act on the search hit for later pasting, for example, `dgn`.

If you do not have this pattern, but rather have a start and end regex, then simply put the cursor at the end of the "start" pattern (e.g. with `/pattern/e`) and then delete until a search hit for the end pattern, e.g. `d/pattern2`.